# Type mismatch error while reading lotus notes document in vb6

Tags: vb6, lotus-notes

Am trying to read the lotus notes document using VB6.I can able to read the values of the but suddenly type mismatch error is throwed.When i reintialise the vb6 variable it works but stops after certain point.

ex; address field in lotus notes

```
lsaddress=ImsField(doc.address)

private function ImsField(pValue)
ImsField=pValue(0)
end function
```

Like this I am reading the remaining fields but at certain point the runtime error "13" type mismatch error throwed.

I have to manually reintialize by

```
 set doc=view.getdocumentbykey(doclist)
```

Answer (score 3):

The type mismatch error occurs for a certain field. The issue should be a data type incompatibility. Try to figure out which field causes the error.

Use `GetItemValue()` instead of short notation for accessing fields and don't use `ImsField()`:

```
lsaddress=doc.GetItemValue("address")(0)
```

Comment: Its a old program that has many intances of assigning values from lotus notes.It might be easier to have a common function.

Comment: It is not about which field that cause this error, I guess it depends on the position.Even if i change the order of the field also it throws the error.For example if the error is throwed while accessing fourth field, it errors out what ever field that is in fourth place.are you getting my point?

Comment: Might be it cannot depend on position.I tested it that ImsField function cannot be used fifth time. on the fifth time it throws error

Comment: I edited answer - please try using getItemValue() - you'll see it will survive the fifth time :)

Answer (score 1):

The type mismatch is occurring because you are encountering a case where pValue is not an array.  That will occur when you attempt to reference a NotesItem that does not exist.  I.e., doc.MissingItem.

You should not use the shorthand notation doc.itemName.  It is convenient, but it leads to sloppy coding.  You should use getItemValue as everyone else is suggesting, and also you should *check to see if the NotesItem exists*.  I.e.,

```
if doc.hasItem("myItem") then
  lsaddress=doc.getItemValue("myItem")(0)
end if
```

Notes and Domino are schema-less.  There are no data integrity checks other than what you write yourself.  You may think that the item always has to be there, but the truth is that there is nothing that will ever guarantee that, so it is always up to you to write your code so that it doesn't assume anything.

BTW: There are other checks that you might want to perform besides just whether or not the field exists.  You might want to check the field's type as well, but to do that requires going one more level up the object chain and using getFirstItem instead of getItemValue, which I'm not going to get into here.  And the reason, once again, is that Notes and Domino are schema-less.  You might think that a given item must always be a text list, but all it takes is someone writing sloppy code in an one-time fix-it agent and you could end up having a document in which that item is numeric!

Checking your fields is actually a good reason (sometimes) to encapsulate your field access in a function, much like the way you have attempted to do.  The reason I added "sometimes" above is that your code's behavior for a missing field isn't necessarily always going to be the same, but for cases where you just want to return a default value when the field doesn't exist you can use something like this:

```
lsaddress ImsField("address","")

private function ImsField(fieldName,defaultValue)
    if doc.hasItem(fieldName) then
      lsaddress=doc.getItemValue(fieldName)(0)
    else
      lsaddress=defaultValue
    end if
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Type mismatch comes,

When you try to set values from one kind of datatype variable to different datatype of another variable.

```
Eg:-

dim x as String
Dim z as variant
z= Split("Test:XXX",":")
x=z
```

The above will through the error what you mentioned.

So check the below code...

> **lsaddress = ImsField(doc.address)**

- What is the datatype of lsaddress?
- What is the return type of ImsField(doc.address)?

  - If the above function parameter is a string, then you should pass the parameter like        (doc.address(0))

Comment: But when I reintialise the doc variable (object) it works fine.How is that possible?

Comment: Where do you initialize the document object? Is it an event?

Comment: This doc is initialized at the beginning.The point of error is different each time.if the error occurs then I will paste the line set doc=view.getdocumentbykey(doclist) which reintializes again.

Comment: ((doc.address(0)) is showing error " variable uses an automation type not supported in visual basic"